# Make picture shows exactly full screen, not exceed the height of screen even on different size screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have a very large picture, say 1900px width and 1333px height, that cause you have to scroll down a little bit to see what's next, is there a way to make the picture shows exactly the same height and width as the screen even on different device?

Thanks! You can find the picture I am talking about at http://dive.maxinrui.com

the code is 
`<section class="box">
       <img src="images/background1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
       <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h1>Welcome to ABI DIVE</h1>
       </div>
    </section>`

Comment: That depends... Is this picture an `<img>` tag or is it a `background-image`? Post your code here in your post rather than link to an external site.

Comment: _“is there a way to make the picture shows exactly the same height and width as the screen even on different device”_ – that would distort the image dimensions, and depending on the aspect ratio of any given screen would most likely look quite poor … I can’t imagine this is what you _really_ want.

Comment: There is a [jQuery plugin called Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/) that is very easy to use and handles all of this for you. If you're open to jQuery I would recommend checking it out. It's nice because it maintains proportions and resizes as the window resizes - but it may cut off portions of the image in order to maintain proportions which is unavoidable unless you have areas of the background with no image.

Comment: @XinruiMa woman actually, but you're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you can get the size of the window or your document using jQuery methods:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Give your img tag an id and then set the height of that img element with CSS.

Comment: Javascript should not be used for CSS purposes!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS3:

```
    html { background-image: url('your_pic.png');
           background-size: cover;
    }
```